# Likelihood of mixed discrete-continuous data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, mixed-type-data

I'm struggling with the derivation of the likelihood with mixed continuous and discrete variables. Let us take this simple example:
\begin{align*}
X &= \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{with probability } 1-p\\
      1 & \text{with probability } p
    \end{cases}, \\
Y &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma) \\ 
Z &= \begin{cases}
      Y & \text{when } X=1\\
      a & \text{when } X=0
    \end{cases}. \\
\end{align*}
We only observe $Z$ in the data, and I want to derive the likelihood of observing $Z=z$ in order to estimate $(\mu, \sigma)$ by maximum likelihood. Assume we know $p$.

But I obtain some weird derivation when deriving the likelihood and I cannot understand why/how to get rid of it. Indeed, I find that:
\begin{align*} l_Z(z) &= l_{Z|X=1}(z) \ \text{Pr}(X=1) + l_{Z|X=0}(z) \ \text{Pr}(X=0) \\
&= l_{Z|X=1}(z) \ p + l_{Z|X=0}(z) \ (1-p) 
\end{align*}

So far, so good. At every value of $z \neq a$, we have $l_{Z|X=0}(z) = 0$ and we know $X=1$. But at $z = a$, I get:
\begin{align*} l_Z(a) &= l_{Z|X=1}(a) \ p + l_{Z|X=0}(a) \ (1-p).
\end{align*}
This is totally counterintuitive, and also wrong I think, because obviously, when $X=0$, no matter what $Y$ is, we get $Z=a$, so this happens for a mass $1-p$ of points. While, when $X=1$, the distribution is continuous, and so $\text{Pr}(Z=a | X=1) \rightarrow 0$. But in terms of likelihood, the term does not cancels out. So I don't know what's wrong with my computation/why I cannot write it like that.

Another way to state the problem is that, I'm also supposed to have:
\begin{align*} l_{Z|X=1}(a) \ \text{Pr}(X=1) = l_Z(a) \ \text{Pr}(X=1 | Z=a) 
\end{align*}
But intuitively, $\text{Pr}(X=1 | Z=a)$ should be zero because of the continuity. But on the left hand side, both terms are different from zero.
So I don't know how to get rid of this term in a "clean" way, when I'm doing my computation.

Comment: You can write the distribution of $Z$ as $p\mathcal N(z|\mu,\sigma) + (1-p)\delta(z-a)$, the problem is that it is not defined at $z=a$ because of the $\delta$-function, so to write the likelihood you will probably have to express it as some limit. Likelihoods are sometimes densities and sometimes probabilities so you have to be careful when dealing with this kind of mixtures (which is probably the point this exercise is trying to demonstrate)

Comment: It's not an exercise, I stumbled upon a more complicated case in my own research but tried to make it as the most simple example I could think of to illustrate the issue as you say. I thought I could apply standard probabilities/densities formula to likelihood but I was wrong it seems. I'm just struggling to understand where it's wrong. Do I have to go back to the cdf instead of the densities to make it appear clearly?

Comment: loosely speaking you can replace $\delta(z-a)$ with some very large constant $\Lambda$ when $z=a$ and neglect the other term (thinking of the limit $\Lambda \to \infty$), so you will end up with the simple $f(z) = p\mathcal N(z|\mu,\sigma)$ when $z \ne a$ and $f(z) = (1-p)\Lambda$ when $z=a$.